# How to sort through a dictionary (a real world dictionary) that is in a .csv file?

Tags: sql, database, csv

I haven't read enough theory or have had enough practice in CS, but there must be a simpler, faster way to look up data from a file. I'm working with a literal, real world dictionary .csv file, and I'm wondering how I can speed up look up of every word. No doubt going through the whole list for the word does not make sense; splitting the file into a-z order, and only looking there for each word, makes sense.

But what else? Should I learn SQL or something and try to convert the text database into an SQL database? Are there methods in SQL that would enable me to do what I wish? Please give me ideas!

Answer (score 1):

SQLite sounds fit to this task.
Create a table, import your csv file, create an index and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this using interop with a moderate size .csv file given me by a supply company. It worked well, but still requires a considerable delay due to the cumbersome decorators used in interop/COM.

```
class Excel
    {
        private excel.Application application;
        private excel.Workbook excelWorkBook;
        protected const string WORD_POSITION = "A"; //whichever column the word is  located in when loaded on Excel spreadsheet.
        protected const string DEFINITION_POSITION = "B"; // whichever column the definition is loaded into on Excel spreadsheet.
        Dictionary<string,string> myDictionary = new Dicationary<string,string>();

        public Excel(string path) // where path is the fileName
        {
            try
            {

                application = new excel.Application();
                excelWorkBook = application.Workbooks.Add(path);
                int row = 1;
                while (application.Cells[++row, WORD_POSITION].Value != null)
                {                                    
                    myDictionary[GetValue(row, WORD_POSITION)] = GetValue(row, DEFINITION_POSITION);
                    });
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                excelWorkBook.Close();
                application.Quit();
            }
        }

        private string GetValue(int row, string columnName)
        {
            string returnValue = String.Empty;            
            returnValue = application.Cells[row, columnName].Value2;
            if (returnValue == null) return string.Empty;                
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Make sure to add the reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and the using directive.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sql database, import the cab into a new table, place an index on the column that stores the word values, then search against table... That is the approach I would take